# null pointer exception error in http POST request JSON object

Tags: java, android, json, apache, http-post

I am doing android coding and sending a http POST request using httpClient. and it is giving me a null point expception error at the line

```
 httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

i used log cat and found that my code was stopping at the line mentioned above. please help me out with it. thanks in advance.

my code is for the establishment of http client is in the file serviceHandler:

```
package com.example.manumaheshwari.vigo;

/**
 * Created by ManuMaheshwari on 30/06/15.
 */

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

StringBuilder sb;


public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded ");

            if (params != null) {

                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "utf-8"));
                }
                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // writing error to Log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Making HTTP Request
                try {

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    // writing response to log
                    Log.d("Http Response:  ", response.toString());




                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // writing exception to log
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }


        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}

}
```

and the code for my main activity is as follows:

```
package com.example.manumaheshwari.vigo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get pending rides JSON
private static String url = "http://128.199.206.145/vigo/v1/displayalldrivers";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SOURCE = "source";
private static final String TAG_DESTINATION = "destination";
private static final String TAG_DRIVER_ID = "driver_id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// pending rides JSONArray
JSONArray pendingRides = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> pendingRidesList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    pendingRidesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetRides().execute();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetRides extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contractor_id", "1"));



        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST, nameValuePairs);

        Log.d("Response: "  , "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                pendingRides = jsonObj.getJSONArray("driver");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < pendingRides.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = pendingRides.getJSONObject(i);

                    String source = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String destination = c.getString(TAG_DRIVER_ID);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> pendingRide = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    pendingRide.put(TAG_NAME, source);
                    pendingRide.put(TAG_DRIVER_ID, destination);


                    // adding pending ride to pending ride list
                    pendingRidesList.add(pendingRide);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, pendingRidesList,
                R.layout.list_view, new String[] { TAG_SOURCE, TAG_DESTINATION,}, new int[] { R.id.source,R.id.destination});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should make sure all your code is indented with four spaces so that Stack Overflow can properly format it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `httpResponse` is null,because in POST method you didn't assign any value to it.So in POST method,change

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

// writing response to log
Log.d("Http Response:  ", response.toString());
```

to

```
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

 // writing response to log
Log.d("Http Response:  ", httpResponse.toString());
```